# Is cout << (i++) << (i++) Undefined behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior

I'm thinking what the output of `int i = 0; cout << (i++) << (i++);` is in c++11.

As my understanding, this code can be transformed into `operator<<(operator<<(cout, i++), i++)`. Am I right?

I thought it would print `01`, however, in my Ubuntu system, it printed `10`.

Why? Is it an UB or not? If it's an UB, does it mean that `f(g(i++), i++)` is UB too? If it's not an UB, why was the output `10`, instead of `01`?

Comment: Please don't att irrelevant tags, like the C tag for what clearly can only be a C++ question.

Comment: As for your problem, it's definitely UB. Arguments to functions can be evaluated in any order, and all overloaded operators are implemented as functions.

Comment: Mind you, the previous comment is only correct because you tagged it with the obsolete C++11 tag.